# How are spell slots for an Eldritch Knight fighter 3/Arcane Trickster rogue 3 determined?

Tags: dnd-5e, multi-classing, rogue, spell-slots, eldritch-knight

The [multi-classing rules subsection on spell slots](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/customization-options#Spellcasting) says:

> ***Spell Slots.*** You determine your available spell slots by adding together all your levels in the **bard, cleric, druid, sorcerer, and wizard classes, and half your levels (rounded down) in the paladin and ranger classes**. Use this total to determine your spell slots by consulting the Multiclass Spellcaster table.

Does this mean that a Eldritch Knight fighter 3/Arcane Trickster rogue 3 has 0 spell slots?

Both of these classes use the Wizard spell list, if that makes a difference.

I am not asking if multiclassed spellcasters share spell slots; I am asking based on the basic rules how they are calculated for these specific classes. Where do the rules address multiclass spellcasting involving the Eldritch Knight fighter or Arcane Trickster rogue?

Comment: Note that you're looking at the basic rules, which don't include those 2 subclasses. Related: [Multiclass Spellcaster: Do the involved classes share the same pool of spell slots?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/123731/multiclass-spellcaster-do-the-involved-classes-share-the-same-pool-of-spell-slo)

Comment: As an aside: Don't do it! I dug into it once for a particular character concept, but the rounding rules make an EK/AT significantly behind the curve on available spell slots. You're self-nerfing.

Comment: @T.J.L. That's fine. Rogue's archetypes are underwhelming, AT is the most useful to me. A 3 level dip into EK gives fighting style, second wind, action surge, 2 bonded weapons, some free slots, and some big hit die. For 2 more levels you can pick up extra attack. I think it's a pretty good deal!

Comment: @jgn Well, if you're going to Fighter 5 for Extra Attack, you might as well take Fighter to 6 so you get the spell slots and the ASI.

Comment: @T.J.L. It's a real rabbit hole :)

Comment: I don't think this should be a duplicate. The asker of the linked question already understands the answer to this one, and is asking a different question instead. This question's more about "where do the rules address multiclass spellcasting involving the EK/AT", not about "do multiclass spellcasters share slots".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## One third of the levels of each

In the [multiclass spellcasting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/phb/customization-options#Spellcasting) rules in the *Player's Handbook* (page 164), the Arcane Trickster and Eldritch Knight are mentioned as counting one third of their levels in Rogue and Fighter, rounded down.

> You determine your available spell slots by adding together all your levels in the bard, cleric, druid, sorcerer, and wizard classes, half your levels (rounded down) in the paladin and ranger classes, and a third of your fighter or rogue levels (rounded down) if you have the Eldritch Knight or the Arcane Trickster archetypes.

An Arcane Trickster 3/Eldritch Knight 3 would have spell slots as 2nd level on the [Multiclass Spellcaster](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/customization-options#MulticlassSpellcaster) table, which is 3 1st-level slots.

The reason you didn't find them in the link you provided is because the basic rules/SRD don't include the Arcane Trickster rogue subclass or Eldritch Knight fighter subclass, which is why the multiclass spellcasting rules there don't account for those 2 subclasses.