# Does a warlock9/sorcerer3 gets 5th or 2nd lvl spell slot when leveling as sorcerer?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, multi-classing, sorcerer, spell-slots

In the description of sorcerer it is stated:
"You learn an additional sorcerer spell of your choice at each level except 12th, 14th, 16th, 18th, 19th, and 20th. **Each of these spells must be of a level for which you have spell slots**."

Since my player has 5th lvl slots because of warlock 9, does he get lvl 5 spells? Because he has a spellslot of this lvl...

I can houserule as the dm, of course, but what is the RAW?
for RAI I would honestly say no.

Comment: Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/167040/how-do-i-determine-how-many-spell-slots-i-have-when-multiclassing and https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/151000/if-i-multiclass-into-2-or-more-spellcasting-classes-how-do-i-determine-my-known

Comment: Welcome ! Specifying the game system would be a very helpful hint to help find an anwser to your question

Comment: I have little doubt this is asking about D&D 5e (stating what game system you're using is a good idea in general though), so I've marked it as a dupe of the Q&A which should cover this. If that question doesn't (including if this isn't actually about D&D 5e), do please tell us why and we'll see what needs to be done to help.

Comment: Sidenote which is not vital to your question, but there's an odd mismatch between your quote and the official versions I'm familiar with (SRD/BR/PHB), in that the official versions just refer to the sorcerer table as opposed to listing excepted levels. It seems to be the same information, though it signals the version you're looking at has some rewrites, so it may contain other discrepancies (and mostly as future ref, you might want to explicitly state what source you're quoting from. Could mitigate some confusion).