# Excessively multiclassed character - how many spell slots?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, multi-classing

One of my friends is willing to run a truly insane campaign where I get to play a "jack of all trades" character, called Jack Sedart of course, who is the following classes;

- lv 1 Barbarian
- lv 3 Bard (base class)
- lv 1 Cleric
- lv 1 Druid
- lv 1 Fighter
- lv 1 Monk
- lv 1 Paladin
- lv 1 Ranger
- lv 1 Rogue
- lv 1 Sorcerer
- lv 1 Warlock
- lv 1 Wizard

The PHB makes no mention of what to do with your Warlock levels when calculating multiclassing spell slots. Am I a level 8 spellcaster (everything but warlock) or a level 9 spellcaster (everything including warlock as a full level) or something else?

(For the curious: yes, I've got the 13s to be legal. I'm playing a human, I have 14/14/13/13/13/14. Trust me, this is not a power build. This is basically an un-power-build. Foolishness ahoy! But the campaign is built for this kind of foolishness to be fun.)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You're level 8 for the purposes of the multiclass spellcaster table.

> **Spell Slots.** You determine your available spell slots by adding together all your levels in the bard, cleric, druid, sorcerer, and wizard classes, half your levels (rounded down) in the paladin and ranger classes, and a third of your fighter or rogue levels (rounded down) if you have the Eldritch Knight or the Arcane Trickster feature. Use this total to determine your spell slots by consulting the Multiclass Spellcaster table.

3 Bard + 1 Cleric + 1 Druid + 1 Sorcerer + 1 Wizard + (Paladin 1 + Ranger 1) / 2 = 8. Warlocks are not included, and you don't have enough Fighter or Rogue levels to count as more than 0.

Your Pact Magic spell slots from the Warlock class are separate, but can be used to cast spells from other classes:

> **Pact Magic.** If you have both the Spellcasting class feature and the Pact Magic class feature from the warlock class, you can use the spell slots you gain from the Pact Magic feature to cast spells you know or have prepared from classes with the Spellcasting class feature, and you can use the spell slots you gain from the Spellcasting class feature to cast warlock spells you know.

So, just to be clear, you have:

- two 4th-level slots,
- three 3rd-level slots,
- three 2nd-level slots, and
- four 1st-level slots from your combined Spellcasting features, and
- one 1st-level spell slot from your Pact Magic feature as a Warlock.

You can cast any spell you have from any of your classes using any of your spell slots, as long as the level of the slot is greater than or equal to the level of the spell. Your Pact Magic slot will be recovered by a short rest, where all your other slots are recovered by a long rest. Your Arcane Recovery from your Wizard class will regain one 1st-level Spellcasting feature slot when used.

Comment: Interesting, in roll20 it seems to do the math as (class[1] + class[1])/2 = 1 rather than class[1]/2 + class[1]/2 = 0, which is how I got 8 as a base. Can you include anything proving/disproving this logic?

Comment: @Alex Ah, you're right. I misread that, sorry - I'll fix it up.

Comment: Additionally you can mostly only cast 1st-level spells with those slots, the exception being 2nd-level Bard spells, [due to simply having no “spells known” access to higher-level spells](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/68604/can-you-cast-a-9th-level-spell-if-your-multiclass-spell-slots-have-9th-level-spe).

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I'm not sure that's the link you wanted, but yes.

Comment: AH, whoops. I fixed that link. :)

Comment: One other thing worth noting about this build - you get cantrips separately from each class, even if you're multiclassing. So with your build, you'll have at least 16 cantrips from a variety of classes (possibly more depending on sub-classes).

Comment: @Alex and miniman: I think Miniman's first calculation was the correct one.  See this (copy and paste the URL) : https://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/11/17/paladin-3ranger-5-caster-level-⌊3252⌋4-or-⌊32⌋⌊52⌋3/

Comment: Also, keep in mind that you have to use the spellcasting modifier for the class that grants you the spell.  I.e., if you prepare a Cleric spell that you also know as a Wizard (but did not memorize), then you'll have to use Wisdom to cast it for today.  Ditto on cantrips.  So if you end up getting better at one ability, try to pick cantrips like *Light* and *Guidance* where the ability scores don't matter for the classes with a low modifier (if you care).

Comment: Also be aware that you'll only have first level spells for all classes but Bard where you'll have first and second level. In addition, be aware of spells you can prepare/know vs must pick not change without levelling in that class.